# Comparing the 2 arrays and if the id's are matching we need to enable the radio buttons if not disable

Tags: reactjs

arrOne:
[ "123_3",
"456_6",
"789_9",
"123_23"
]

arrTwo:

[ "453_3",
"456_6",
"789_9",
"111_13"
]
I have tried to
const isDisabled = this.state.arrOne.some(item => this.state.arrTwo.includes(item));

return <Radio disabled={isDisabled}

Comment: Do you want :
- to check button if the id exists in both arrays ?
- to check button if elements at same indices match ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `every` instead `some`:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    arrOne: ['123_3', '456_6', '789_9', '123_23'],
    arrTwo: ['453_3', '456_6', '789_9', '111_13']
  });
const isDisabled = !state.arrOne.every(item => state.arrTwo.includes(item));
```